# ¿Cómo definir un array según la entrada?

Tags: c++, array

```
int piezas = 0, procesos=0;
cout<< "Digite cantidad de pizas a procesar\n";
cin >> piezas;
cout << "Digite cantidad de procesos a evaluar\n";
cin >> procesos;



double steel[piezas][procesos];
getTimes(steel);
```

El compilador me genera error, *int piezas & int procesos must have a constant value* justo en esta parte `double steel[piezas][procesos];`mas alla de la solución no entiendo esta parte de c++ yo esto mas familiarizado a JAVA.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problema.

Utilizas Arreglos de Longitud Variable ([VLA en inglés [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)), los cuáles no pertenecen al C++ estándar si no que son una extensión del compilador (Lee sobre la extensión en [el compilador GCC [image]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)). Cada compilador tiene sus propias extensiones de manera que es posible que este código te funcione en determinados compiladores.

Según el [estándar de C++ [image]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 8.3.4 Arreglos
>
> 1. En una declaración `T D` en que `D` tiene la forma
>
>    **`D1 [` *expresión-constante*<sub>*opcional*</sub> `]` *secuencia-especificación-atributo*<sub>*opcional*</sub>**
>
>    y el tipo del identificador en la declaración `T D1` es "*declarador-tipo-lista* `T`", entonces el tipo del identificador de `D` es arreglo; [...]

Este galimatías viene a decir que para crear un arreglo de la manera en que lo estás haciendo es imposible (sea de las dimensiones que sea), ya que los tamaños en la definición del array deben ser constantes conocidas en [tiempo de compilación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_compilaci%C3%B3n), pero el valor de `piezas` y `procesos` sólo se conoce en [tiempo de ejecución](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n).

#### Solución.

Usa memoria dinámica. La solución propuesta por [Mario Rodríguez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64882/2742) en **la primera parte** de su respuesta **es correcta y funcional**:

```
int piezas = 0, procesos=0;
std::cout<< "Digite cantidad de pizas a procesar\n";
std::cin >> piezas;
std::cout << "Digite cantidad de procesos a evaluar\n";
std::cin >> procesos;

double **steel = new double*[piezas];

for (int i = 0; i < piezas; i++)
    steel[i] = new double[procesos];

for (int y = 0; y < piezas; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < procesos; ++x)
        steel[x][y] = x + (y * piezas);

for (int y = 0; y < piezas; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < procesos; ++x)
        std::cout << steel[x][y] << '\n';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mGTE2zaty7gSSSJB)</kbd>.

Mas **la segunda no sigue el estándar** y no compilará en compiladores sin soporte a VLA. El guardar una variable conocida en tiempo de ejecución en una variable constante no la transforma en una expresión constante (valor conocido en tiempo de compilación).

#### Propuesta: arreglo 1D tratado como 2D.

La solución anterior suele dispersar los datos por memoria, posibilitando una baja [localidad de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercan%C3%ADa_de_referencias), lo cuál afectaría al rendimiento, para solucionarlo puedes crear el arreglo en una dimensión pero tratarlo como dos dimensiones:

```
int piezas = 0, procesos=0;
std::cout<< "Digite cantidad de pizas a procesar\n";
std::cin >> piezas;
std::cout << "Digite cantidad de procesos a evaluar\n";
std::cin >> procesos;

double *steel = new double[piezas * procesos];
//     ^^ Puntero!

for (int y = 0; y < piezas; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < procesos; ++x)
        steel[x + (y * piezas)] = x + (y * piezas);

for (int y = 0; y < piezas; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < procesos; ++x)
        std::cout << steel[x + (y * piezas)] << '\n';
```

Esta aproximación, además de garantizar que todos los datos estarán anexos en memoria, te ahorra el proceso de inicializar cada sub-dimensión del arreglo.

#### Propuesta: olvida `new` y `delete`.

Todas las soluciones anteriores tienen en común que debes solicitar manualmente la memoria y en consecuencia debes liberarla manualmente (ninguno de los ejemplos incluye liberación de memoria). Este proceso de liberar memoria puede ser tedioso y propenso a errores, así que mejor usemos [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), que nos facilita todo, incluida la gestión de memoria:

```
int piezas = 0, procesos=0;
std::cout<< "Digite cantidad de pizas a procesar\n";
std::cin >> piezas;
std::cout << "Digite cantidad de procesos a evaluar\n";
std::cin >> procesos;

// Construye un vector de 'piezas * procesos' elementos con valor '0.'.
std::vector<double> Steel(piezas * procesos, 0.);

for (int y = 0; y < piezas; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < procesos; ++x)
        steel[x + (y * piezas)] = x + (y * piezas);

for (int y = 0; y < piezas; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < procesos; ++x)
        std::cout << steel[x + (y * piezas)] << '\n';
```

Usando `std::vector` obtenemos:

1. Buena localidad de datos.
2. Gestión automática de memoria.
3. Mismo tipo de acceso que con arreglos.

Comment: Muy agradecido con tu ayuda, me gustaría instalar la extensión al compilador (visual studio) como lo descargo?

Answer (score 1):

Para poder inicializar un array de 2D "estático" el tamaño tanto de las filas como el las columnas debe ser constante.
En este caso, una posible solución puede ser la de implementar la creación de un array dinámico a partir de las entradas, siendo `piezas` los datos de las filas y `procesos` los datos de las columnas:

```
double** steel = new double*[piezas];
for (int i = 0; i < piezas; i++)
    steel[i] = new double[procesos];

getTimes(steel);
```

Sin olvidar luego que hay que liberar memoria al finalizar al tratarse de memoria dinámica (importante).

Si por el contrario, no te importa la eficiencia y, además, prefieres olvidarte de liberar memoria al final puedes hacer un pequeño cambio en tu código original de esta forma:

```
int piezas = 0, procesos=0;
cout<< "Digite cantidad de pizas a procesar\n";
cin >> piezas;
cout << "Digite cantidad de procesos a evaluar\n";
cin >> procesos;

const int TAM_FILA = piezas ;
const int TAM_COL = procesos ;
double steel[TAM_FILA][TAM_COL];

getTimes(steel);
```

Todo depende del uso que posteriormente se le vaya a dar al array en cuestión (si se va a tener que modificar su longitud u otra gestión similar) y de los requerimientos de dicho programa.
Sin embargo, esta opción no cumple los *estándares ISO C++* sino que se utilizan las extensiones provenidas del compilador.

Comment: La primera parte, con memoria dinámica, OK. La segunda ... no se yo, pero me parece que el *mensajito* `must have a constant value` quiere decir otra cosa ...

Comment: El mensaje quiere decir exactamente lo que he demostrado. Puedes compilar y probar el funcionamiento libre de errores y warnings en ambos casos.

Comment: Curioso. A mi me sigue dando **2** *warning*s: [`warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'steel'`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6KjTTGTuj6l6iusp)

Comment: Pues no sé @Trauma, mi compilador incluso con `-Wall`no imprime nada. De todas formas he depurado y probado el programa llenando el array y funciona bien igualmente.

Comment: Si es `gcc` prueba con `-std=c++11 -pedantic`, para que siga el estándar. Funcionar, va a funcionar de lujo, pero la parte que te indico no cumple los estándares, sino que hace uso de las *extensiones* del compilador. Adviertelo en tu respuesta, y listo :-)

Comment: Después de añadirle `pedantic`, ahora sí que me aparecen. Corregido, muchas gracias.

Comment: `steel[TAM_FILA][TAM_COL]` no es correcto. Teniendo en cuenta que `TAM_FILA` y `TAM_COL` no son conocidos en tiempo de compilación, dan como resultado que `steel` sea un VLA que es una característica **no admitida** en el estándar de C++. Para valores aleatorios hay que usar `new`

Comment: @MarioRodríguez declaras mal el arreglo, debe ser `double **steel = new double*[piezas];`.

Comment: Arreglada la declaración. Gracias