# ¿Como puedo solucionar este error? c++, función malloc y matrices

Tags: c++, matrices, cast

Al ejecutar mi código me sale el siguiente error:

> ```
> matriz.c: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> matriz.c:14:4: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘float*’ to ‘float* [56][64]’
> A =  (float*)malloc(64 * 56 * sizeof(float));
>
> matriz.c:19:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float*’ [-fpermissive]
>  A[i][j] = i * 64 + j;
> ```

El código que ejecuto es el siguiente:

```
int main() {

    const int fila = 56;
    const int columna = 64;

    clock_t inicio = clock();
    int i, j, total = 0;
    float *A [fila][columna];
    A =  (float*)malloc(64 * 56 * sizeof(float));

    for(int k = 0; k<4000; k++)
        for (i = 0; i < 56; i++) 
            for (j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
                A[i][j] = i * 64 + j;
            }


    for(int k = 0; k<4000; k++)
        for (i = 0; i < 56; i++) 
            for (j = 0; j < 64; j++) 
                 A[i][j]+= 1;


    free(A);

    clock_t final = clock();

    printf("El tiempo total es: %f seg \n", (float)(final-inicio)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar estos errores?

Cabe destacar que si esto mismo lo hago con un vector en vez de con una matriz, funciona a la perfección, pero para mi proyecto necesito usar matrices. La función malloc también la necesito para reservar la memoria.

Al final lo que tengo que hacer es leer 4000 matrices, sumarles una unidad y que el tiempo que tarde en hacerlo sea menor que 0.1s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una matriz declarada tal que:

```
float A[3][3];
```

Tiene un comportamiento bastante diferente a:

```
float **A;
```

En el primer caso los diferentes valores que componen el array se encuentran en posiciones consecutivas de la memoria, mientras que en el segundo caso cada fila se encontrará en una posición aleatoria de la memoria. Esto es importante porque explica ciertas restricciones con las que te vas a encontrar.

Por otro lado, pese a que no pueda parecer así, con

```
float* A[fila][columna];
```

No estás declarando un puntero a una matriz... sino una matriz de punteros... cosas del lenguaje. La forma correcta de declarar el puntero sería así:

```
float (*A)[fila][columna];
```

Vale, ahora veamos que pasa con la asignación:

```
A =  (float*)malloc(64 * 56 * sizeof(float));
```

En C++ el tipado es fuerte y esto implica que conversiones entre tipos que no se parecen en nada no está permitido... en este caso un puntero a una matriz y un puntero a float... como que no es lo mismo.

Como la sintaxis del puntero a matriz es ya de por sí engorroso quizás la opción más sencilla es tirar de `decltype` (disponible desde C++11):

```
A = reinterpret_cast<decltype(A)>(new float[fila*columna]);

delete[] A; // en sustitución de free(A)
```

Por otro lado nota que he sustituido `malloc` por `new` y la razón es sencilla: Si programas en C++ **no uses** funcionalidad propia de C salvo que sea estrictamente necesario.

Si no puedes hacer uso del estándar C++11 o superior (y mira que hablamos de un estándar con 6 años de antigüedad...) tendrás que hacer el cast a mano:

```
A = reinterpret_cast<float(*)[fila][columna]>(new float[fila*columna]);
```

Mola la sintaxis, ¿verdad?

Vale, ya has hecho la asignación... ahora vamos a por errores que aun no te han llegado a salir:

```
prog.cc:18:25: error: array type 'float [64]' is not assignable
                A[i][j] = i * 64 + j;
                ~~~~~~~ ^
prog.cc:25:25: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('float [64]' and 'int')
                 A[i][j]+= 1;
                 ~~~~~~~^
```

En definitiva. Si `A` es un puntero a una matriz tienes que usar el operador `*` para acceder a los elementos apuntados:

```
*A[i][j] = i * 64 + j;
```

Aunque por claridad yo casi preferiría ponerlo así:

```
(*A)[i][j] = i * 64 + j;
```

Comment: Ha funcionado a la perfección, muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

El mensaje de error lo dice claro como el cristal (pero en Inglés). Permiteme traducirlo:

> ```
> incompatible types in assignment of ‘float*’ to ‘float* [56][64]’
> invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float*’
> ```

> ```
> tipos incompatibles en la asignación de ‘float*’ a ‘float* [56][64]’
> conversión no válida de ‘int’ a ‘float*’
> ```

#### Problema

Básicamente usas un arreglo de dos dimensiones de **punteros a `float`** y pretendes asignarle un **puntero a `float`**:

```
  float *A [fila][columna];
//^^^^^^^ <-- arreglo de dos dimensiones de punteros a float

  A =  (float*)malloc(64 * 56 * sizeof(float));
      //^^^^^^ <-- puntero a float
```

Por este motivo, cuando intentas asignar un valor entero (que esperas que se transforme a `float`) no te lo acepta porque el arreglo es de **punteros a `float`** no de `float`:

```
  A[i][j] = i * 64 + j;
//^^^^^^^ <-- A[i][j] es 'float *' no 'float'
```

No falla al sumar valores, porque estás haciendo aritmética de punteros:

```
  A[i][j]+= 1;
//^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- avanzo el puntero 'float *' una posición
```

#### Solución

Usa un arreglo de `float`, no un arreglo de punteros a `float`:

```
  float A [fila][columna];
//^^^^^ <-- sin puntero
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta

- En C++ no se usa `malloc` si no `new`.
- La memoria de `A` ya está reservada, no necesitas solicitarla ni mediante `malloc` ni mediante `new`.
- En C++ los punteros tradicionales están casi en desuso, usa contenedores de la [`stl`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library).
- La salida por consola en C++ es mediante [`std::cout`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout), [`std::printf`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) se trata de un vestigio de C.
- No hay garantías (aunque sí muchas probabilidades) de que una variable `const` sea considerada un valor en tiempo de compilación, si quieres forzarlo usa `constexpr` o de lo contrario forzarás un [Arreglo de Longitud Variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64881/c%c3%b3mo-definir-un-array-seg%c3%ban-la-entrada/64988#64988).
- No ganas nada sacando del bucle `for` las variables `i` y `j`.
- A partir de C++11 se dispone de una librería de medida de tiempo [`<chrono>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono), no es necesario usar `clock()`.

Tu código, en C++ moderno se vería así:

```
int main() {

    constexpr int fila = 56;
    constexpr int columna = 64;

    auto inicio = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    float A [fila][columna]{};

    for(int k = 0; k<4000; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 56; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
                A[i][j] = i * 64 + j;
            }

    for(int k = 0; k<4000; k++)
        for (auto &i : A) 
            for (auto &j : i)
                 j += 1;

    auto duracion = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - inicio;

    std::cout << "El tiempo total es: "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(duracion).count()
              << "seg \n";

    return 0;
}
```