# Matriz con datos cambiantes y pasos de tiempo

Tags: c++

Tengo problemas para escribir un programa que debe calcular la temperatura de un punto central de una región rectangular tras ciertos pasos de tiempo.

Para el cual cree una matriz de (N+1)x(M+1) donde N = 2M y el punto central de la región es (N/2)+1 y (M/2)+1. Las celdas superiores tienen una temperatura inicial 20 ºC, el resto de celdas tienen una temperatura inicial de 0 ºC, ademas en las celdas del contorno la temperatura es invariante.

La temperatura en cada celda y  paso de tiempo (Tk) se calcula con la temperatura en el paso de tiempo anterior (Tk-1) de las celdas adyacentes, siguiendo la siguiente formula:

> (Siendo (i,j) el valor de una celda)
>
> T = (4*[(i+1,j)+(i-1,j)+(i,j+1)+(i,j-1)]+[(i-1,j-1)+(i-1,j+1)+(i+1,j+1)+(i+1,j-1)])/10

Hasta aquí lo tengo todo claro y no tengo mayor problema. El problema empieza cuando para calcular la temperatura tras cada paso de tiempo suma la temperatura ya calculada en el propio salto de tiempo en vez de utilizar la temperatura del anterior salto de tiempo, es decir:

Para calcular la temperatura de la celda (1,6) utiliza las celdas adyacentes, pero anteriormente ya calculó la celda (1,5), y en vez de utilizar la temperatura de (1,5) antes del calculo, la suma después de dicho calculo dando un resultado erróneo.

Hasta ahora tengo escrito lo siguiente:

```
int main( ) {
  int N = 20;   
  int M = 10;
  int A = 2 * N + 1;
  int B = 2 * M + 1;
  int matriz[A][B];

  for( int i = 1; i < A; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < B; j++ ) {      
      matriz[0][j] = 20;
      matriz[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  for( int i = 1; i < ( A - 1 ); i++ ) {
    for( int j = 1; j < ( B - 1 ); j++ ) {
      int n = i - 1;
      int e = j + 1;
      int s = i + 1;
      int o = j - 1;
      int T = ( 4 * ( matriz[n][j] + matriz[s][j] + matriz[i][o] + matriz[i][e] ) + ( matriz[n][e] + matriz[n][o] + matriz[s][e] + matriz[s][o] ) ) / 10;
      matriz[i][j] += matriz[i][j] + T;
    }
  } 
  std::cout << matriz[N + 1][M + 1];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ojo, tus matrices están mal. Estás usando variables para declarar su tamaño y eso no es C++ estándar. Tampoco entiendo por qué tus bucles van de `1` a `tamaño - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

> Para calcular la temperatura de la celda (1,6) utiliza las celdas adyacentes, pero anteriormente ya calculó la celda (1,5), y en vez de utilizar la temperatura de (1,5) antes del calculo, la suma después de dicho calculo dando un resultado erróneo.

Normal, en cada pasada estás escribiendo los valores, no puedes usar los valores previos al cálculo si al cacular el valor lo actualizas. Necesitas una copia de los valores antes del cálculo. Mi consejo es que uses un [búfer múltiple](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_m%C3%BAltiple).

Para implementar un doble búfer yo usaría una función de actualización que recibiera dos matrices: la de referencia (datos que no se cambiarán) y la de cálculo (datos que serán escritos):

```
constexpr int N = 20;   
constexpr int M = 10;
constexpr int A = 2 * N + 1;
constexpr int B = 2 * M + 1;
using Matriz = int[A][B];

void actualiza(const Matriz &origen, Matriz &destino)
{
  for( int i = 1; i < ( A - 1 ); i++ ) {
    for( int j = 1; j < ( B - 1 ); j++ ) {
      int n = i - 1;
      int e = j + 1;
      int s = i + 1;
      int o = j - 1;
      int T = ( 4 * ( origen[n][j] + origen[s][j] + origen[i][o] + origen[i][e] ) +
                    ( origen[n][e] + origen[n][o] + origen[s][e] + origen[s][o] ) ) / 10;

      destino[i][j] += T;
    }
  } 
}
```

He hecho unos cambios en tu código para que funcione; en primer lugar he cambiado tus valores `N`, `M`, `A` y `B` a expresiones constantes para garantizar que estén disponibles en tiempo de compilación y así poder definir el tipo `Matriz`, que será una formación<sup>1</sup> de dos dimensiones `AxB`, este es el tipo que se le pasará a la función `actualiza` que sigue tu algoritmo.

En segundo lugar he cambiado la instrucción de actualización estabas usando, ya que usabas el operador `+=` usando a su izquierda y derecha el mismo dato junto otro valor, seguramente no querías esto, ya que si (por ejemplo) en la celda `(j,i)` tenías el valor `7` y en `T` el valor `10` el resultado sería:

```
matriz(j,i) += 7 + 10; // matriz(j,i) es 7
matriz(j,i) += 17;     // matriz(j,i) es 7
// matriz(j,i) obtiene el valor 24
```

Para que funcione el búfer múltiple tienes que intercambiar cada matriz en cada llamada a `actualiza`.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Estás usando variables para definir el tamaño de formaciones<sup>1</sup>, se requiere que el tamaño de las formaciones sea un valor constante. Si se usa una variable y te compila significa que estás usando una extensión de compilador conocida como VLA ([*Variable Lenght Array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)), al ser una extensión de compilador significa que si cambias de compilador es probable que el código deje de compilar, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64881/c%C3%B3mo-definir-un-array-seg%C3%BAn-la-entrada) para tener más detalles al respecto.

Teniendo eso en cuenta tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int N = 20;   
constexpr int M = 10;
constexpr int A = 2 * N + 1;
constexpr int B = 2 * M + 1;
using Matriz = int[A][B];

void actualiza(const Matriz &origen, Matriz &destino)
{
  for( int i = 1; i < ( A - 1 ); i++ ) {
    for( int j = 1; j < ( B - 1 ); j++ ) {
      int n = i - 1;
      int e = j + 1;
      int s = i + 1;
      int o = j - 1;
      int Temperatura = ( 4 * ( origen[n][j] + origen[s][j] + origen[i][o] + origen[i][e] ) +
                              ( origen[n][e] + origen[n][o] + origen[s][e] + origen[s][o] ) ) / 10;
      destino[i][j] += Temperatura;
    }
  } 
}

int main()
{
    Matriz matriz1{}, matriz2{};

    for( int j = 0; j < B; j++ ) {      
        matriz1[0][j] = 20;
        matriz2[0][j] = 20;
    }

    constexpr int pasos = 10;
    for (int paso = 0; paso != pasos; ++paso)
    {
        if (paso % 2)
            actualiza(matriz1, matriz2);
        else
            actualiza(matriz2, matriz1);
    }

    std::cout << matriz1[N + 1][M + 1] << '\n'
              << matriz2[N + 1][M + 1];

    return 0;
}
```

Fíjate que para inicializar las matrices hemos usado llaves (`{}`), esto provoca que todos sus elementos sean inicializados a cero (`0`), de manera que al asignar los valores iniciales es necesario un sólo bucle para las celdas superiores.

El bucle de intercambio de búferes lo he hecho lo más sencillo posible, pero puedes escoger cualquier otra implementación.

---

1. También conocido como *arreglo*, o en inglés *array*.