# ¿Como mostrar la cantidad de empleados por sexo?

Tags: c++, algoritmos, struct

Tengo el siguiente código el cual me muestras los datos de N cantidad de empleados ingresados 
Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
¿Como muestro la cantidad de empleados por sexo?

```
int main(void){
               /*Declara las variables para los ciclo for*/
int i = 0, n = 0;

               /*Declara estructura person*/
struct person{
    char dni[14];
    char civil_status[15];
    char sex[15];
};
              /*Declara employee, arreglo de la estructura person*/
struct person employee[max];

/*Se pide cuantos registros de employees se guardaran*/
cout<<"Cuantos datos quieres ingresar? \n";
cin>> n;

              /*Ciclo for que va a recorrer según la cantidad escrita anteriormente*/
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout<<"\n Escriba la Cedula "<< i+1<<":";
    cin>> employee[i].dni;

    cout<<"\n Escriba el Estado Civil "<< i+1<<":";
    cin>> employee[i].civil_status;

    cout<<"\n Escriba el Sexo "<< i+1<<":";
    cin>> employee[i].sex;
}

cout<<"\n El registro de employes que se introdujeron son: \n\n";

/*Ciclo for que muestra el listado de registro ingresados*/
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    /*Se llama al arreglo employee seguido de la variable dni*/
    cout<< employee[i].dni;
    cout<<"\t"<<employee[i].civil_status;
    cout<<"\t"<<employee[i].sex<<"\n\n";
  }
   system("pause");
}
```

Un ejemplo de introducción de datos:

> Cuantos datos quieres ingresar? 2
>   Escriba la Cedula 1:012345
>   Escriba el Estado Civil 1:soltero
>   Escriba el Sexo 1:masculino
>   Escriba la Cedula 2:67891
>   Escriba el Estado Civil 2:casado
>   Escriba el Sexo 2:femenino
>
> El registro de employes que se introdujeron son:
>
> 012345 soltero masculino 67891 casado femenino

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4):

Utiliza [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
using std::literals::string_literals;

auto mujeres = std::count_if(std::begin(employee), std::end(employee),
               [](const person &p) {
                   return p.sex == "femenino"s;
               });
```

Cuentas las mujeres, los hombres resultarán de restar la cantidad de mujeres a `max`, esto te permite evitar contar por separado cada sexo, evitando la necesidad de un `if`, que **afectaría muy negativamente al rendimiento**.

La función `std::count_if` está disponible al incluir la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm), te contará todos los elementos entre el iterador de inicio (primer parámetro) y el iterador de final (segundo parámetro) que cumplan con una condición (el tercer parámetro).

Las funciones [`std::begin` y `std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) están disponibles en la cabecera [`<iterator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator) y son las que calculan el inicio y final de tu formación `employee`.

La instrucción `using std::literals::string_literals;` es la que te permite usar los [literales definidos por el usuario](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) de cadenas de caracteres, por eso en la lambda pasada a `std::count_if` podemos escribir

```
return p.sex == "femenino"s;
```

en lugar de

```
return p.sex == std::string{"femenino"};
```

Puedes no usar los iteradores y aprovechar que `employee` es una formación y aplicar aritmética de punteros:

```
auto mujeres = std::count_if(employee, employee + n,
               [](const person &p) {
                   return p.sex == "femenino"s;
               });
```

Así también esquivas el posible problema de contar mal cuando `n` y `max` no contienen el mismo valor.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

En C++ `struct` no forma parte del tipo, así que no necesitas anteponerlo para declarar estructuras.

---

En C++ las funciones que no reciben parámetros basta con escribirlas con un paréntesis vacío.

---

[La función `main` debe devolver un valor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139624/en-c-es-obligatorio-incluir-el-return-0-dentro-de-la-funci%C3%B3n-main).

---

No se qué tipo tiene `max`, pero si no es un tipo conocido en tiempo de compilación, tendrás problemas de compatibilidad con tu código, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64881/c%C3%B3mo-definir-un-array-seg%C3%BAn-la-entrada) para saber más al respecto.

---

Las variables de los `for` se pueden declarar en los propios bucles, no es necesario hacerlo fuera.

Comment: Ese `auto` va lleno de `mujeres` ...

Comment: Veo que le gusta "linkear" mi pregunta sobre la función `main` xd.

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que tienes dos tipos de sexos, `masculino` y `femenino`.

Simplemente crea un `integer` para cada uno de ellos inicializado a 0, recorre los datos con un `for` y ve incrementando la `cantidad` que hay en cada uno en el `integer` correspondiente:

```
int masculino = 0, femenino = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if(employee[i].sex == "masculino")
        masculino++;
    else if (employee[i].sex == "femenino")
        femenino++;
}
cout << "Número de empleados masculinos: " << masculinos;
cout << "Número de empleados femeninos: " << femeninos;
```

Comment: Lo que has puesto en tu `cout` compila? Me parece que esa no es la sintaxis de C++. Btw, te has "comido" unas comillas al final de la palabra `masculino`. Por último, puedes hacer más sencillos tus bucles haciendo uso de un `range-for loop` (C++11 en adelante).

Comment: @Xam Compila, pero el comportamiento será, curioso. Por ejemplo si hubieran 28 hombres y 28 mujeres se mostraría: `os: 28` y `s: 28` porque se sumaría 28 al literal de cadena. No puede usar el `for` de rango porque no está trabajando sobre la formación completa si no sobre el rango `0-n`.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus hmm, `n` no es el tamaño del arreglo?

Comment: @Xam Toda la razón, no he compilado como suelo hacer porque era un ejemplo sencillo y lo he escrito directamente; y me he confundido con la sintaxis de java. Ya lo he corregido, gracias por avisar! Respecto al `range-for`no se puede hacer como dice @Paula_plus_plus ya que el `n` es el número de datos introducidos y es distinto de `max` (el tamaño del array).

Answer (score -1):

Los datos ya los tenés, solo ténes que contar cuantos registros tienen en su atributo sexo el valor 'masculino' o 'femenino' y contarlos. Puedes definir una variable para cada uno y después mostrarlas, por ejemplo:

```
int cantidadMasculinos = 0;
int cantidadFemeninos = 0;    
/*Ciclo for que muestra el listado de registro ingresados*/
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
 /*Se llama al arreglo employee seguido de la variable dni*/
 cout<< employee[i].dni;
 cout<<"\t"<<employee[i].civil_status;
 cout<<"\t"<<employee[i].sex<<"\n\n";
  if(employee[i].sex = 'masculino'){
   cantidadMasculinos += 1;
   }else{cantidadFemeninos += 1;}
}
cout<<"Cantidad de empleados masculinos: "<<cantidadMasculinos;
cout<<"Cantidad de empleados femeninos: "<<cantidadFemeninos;
system("pause");
}
```