# Separar palabras y guardar en array en C++

Tags: c++, array, string

Estoy intentando de un texto tipo string, separar todas las palabras y luego meterlas en un arreglo. Por ejemplo: Texto="La casa es amarilla" -- Arreglo={"La","casa","es","amarilla"}
No se me ocurre una lógica para darle recorrer el arreglo, darle un stop cuando haya espacio y guardar lo que encontro y luego volver a repetir..
Aqui mi codigo:

```
int main(){
string texto="La casa es amarilla";
int contador=1;
for (int i=0;i<texto.length();i++){
if (texto[i]==' ')
{
    contador++;
}    
}
string palabras[contador];
for (int i=0;i<texto.length();i++){

//No se como seguir
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ocupar otro string a modo de buffer para ir almacenando la letras hasta encontrar un espacio, cuando pase eso vuelcas toda esa información (que sería una palabra) al array

```
int main()
{
    string texto="La casa es amarilla";
    int contador=1;
    for (int i=0;i<texto.length();i++){
        if (texto[i]==' ')
        {
            contador++;
        }    
    }
    
    string palabras[contador];
    string palabraAux="";
    int index=0; //para recorrer el arreglo
    for (int i=0;i<texto.length();i++){
    
        //si es un espacio volcamos todo lo guardado en palabraAux al array
        if (texto[i]==' ')
        {
            palabras[index] = palabraAux;
            index++;
            palabraAux="";
        }
        else{ //si es una letra, la concatenamos a palabraAux para guardarla
            palabraAux+=texto[i];
        }
    }
    //agregamos la última palabra, que siempre quedará fuera del for anterior
    palabras[index] = palabraAux;
    
    //Imprimir resultado
    for (int i=0;i<contador;i++){
        cout<<"\n"<<palabras[i];
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

***Update***

Siguiendo la recomendación de @PaperBirdMaster, y además esta excelente [publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64988/301324) voy a añadir una respuesta utilizando vector.

El único punto a considerar es el contexto de la pregunta original, la cual evidentemente se refiere a alguna tarea de un curso básico de programación, por lo que utilizar este método puede resultar fuera de lugar.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include <vector> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string texto="La casa es amarilla";
    int contador=1;
    for (int i=0;i<texto.length();i++){
        if (texto[i]==' ')
        {
            contador++;
        }    
    }
    
    std::vector<string> palabras(contador);
    string palabraAux;
    int index=0; //para recorrer el arreglo
    for (int i=0;i<texto.length();i++){
    
        //si es un espacio volcamos todo lo guardado en palabraAux al array
        if (texto[i]==' ')
        {
            palabras[index] = palabraAux;
            index++;
            palabraAux="";
        }
        else{ //si es una letra, la concatenamos a palabraAux para guardarla
            palabraAux+=texto[i];
        }
    }
    //agregamos la última palabra, que siempre quedará fuera del for anterior
    palabras[index] = palabraAux;
    
    //Imprimir resultado
    for (int i=0;i<contador;i++){
        cout<<"\n"<<palabras[i];
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow me parecio increible la logica! Tenia pensado algo asi pero no sabia implementarla. Solo tengo una sola duda, por que declaras palabraAux = ""?  Que significa? Y casi olvido agradecerte!

Comment: Intuía que tu solución iba por ese lado. string palabraAux="", es un string vacío, la verdad es que no recuerdo cómo se inicializa un string en C++, así que preferí colocarlo. Pero probablemente si lo sacas no pasa nada (en otros lenguajes si hay que inicializar los string)

Comment: @Yussef el código es incorrecto en la declaración de la formación `palabras`; no debes usar una variable para definir su tamaño.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster y como defines un array de strings??

Comment: @Yussef el problema no es de **qué** es el array si no cómo defines su tamaño. Los array deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación, de una variable sólo se conoce su valor en tiempo de ejecución. Mira [estas preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vla).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99 Desde C99 si se puedo (o es lo que entiendo)

Comment: @Yussef C99 es el estándar del lenguaje [tag:c], pero la pregunta es sobre el lenguaje [tag:c++]. Por otro lado el estándar C99 tiene 23 años de antigüedad, hoy día los VLA no están definidos en el estándar de C y sólo tienen soporte en el lenguaje mediante extensión del compilador.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Muchas gracias por la información. Edité mi respuesta para  colocar una versión que creo se condice con lo que me has señalado

Answer (score 2):

Algo mucho más sencillo, puedes utilizar la función [**`strtok()`**](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) para dividir la cadena con los delimitadores que le definas, en este caso serán los espacios, veamos:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[100] = "La casa es amarilla";
    
    char *ptr;
    ptr = strtok(str, " , ");

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr  << endl;
        ptr = strtok (NULL, " , ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Ouput:**

```
// La
// casa
// es
// amarilla
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando el metodo `substr()` puedes obtener substrings determinado por un rango, siendo el primer argumento la posicion del primer caracter hasta la posicion indicada por el segundo argumento, seria algo como `substr(inicio,fin)` y el fin es delimitado por la posicion del caracter espacio y para obtenerlo se usa el metodo `find(' ')` y su argumento es caracter espacio, luego para que se repita este proceso se elimina del texto la primera palabra usando `erase()` pasando como argumento el mismo rango que se le entrego al substr() pero el segundo argumento incrementado en uno.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string texto = "La casa es amarilla";
    int contador = 1;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++){
        if(texto[i] == ' '){
            contador++;
        }
    }

    string palabras[contador];

    for(int i = 0; i < contador; i++){
        palabras[i] = texto.substr(0,texto.find(' '));
        texto.erase(0,texto.find(' ') + 1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < contador; i++){
        cout<<palabras[i]<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```